# IIS 7 - redirect from HTTPS to HTTP schema not working

Tags: iis-7

I Recently set an aspnet application under win 7 IIS 7 and got enabled SSL for this app.
the app works great under ssl, but when i change the schema from https to http, using a response.redirect, the request get a timeout, i am stuck with it, any idea is welcome.
regards

Comment: I have seen this as well.  I thought it was caused by a proxy server sitting in front of my application but now that I read this perhaps not.  The same application worked well under IIS6.  In my case I worked around it by actually changing the links to hit the HTTP page directly instead of an HTTPS page that redirects to HTTP.  I consider it a workaround but not a solution -- eager to hear the thoughts of others.

Comment: yes , that is true, the application works ok on iis6 :S

Answer (score 1):

You cannot switch protocols unless you provide an absolute URL. The reference must be absolute.

make use of the encryptedUri and unencryptedUri attributes. "unencryptedUri" may be specified to send the user back to another domain or specific URI when the module removes security.

You can have a custom configuration..

```
<secureWebPages
    mode="RemoteOnly"
    encryptedUri="secure.mysite.com"
    unencryptedUri="www.mysite.com"
    maintainPath="True"

    warningBypassMode="AlwaysBypass">


    ...
</secureWebPages>
```

An example would be to redirect secure requests to secure.mysite.com and requests that don't need to be secure could be redirected back to www.mysite.com. maintainPath is used in conjunction with the above attributes. When the module redirects to the encryptedUri or unencryptedUri, it appends the current path before sending users on their way.

Comment: i am using absolutes urls, i am doing a response.redirect from https://mysite.com to http://mysite.com but is not working. regards

Comment: are u referring to http://code.google.com/p/securityswitch/downloads/list? i am looking for a native solution, seems to be a problem on iis7 only, on iis6 works ok